# Transferring to contract from another contract - payable error when transferring

Tags: contract-development, payable, factory

I have a contract (the factory) that deploys other contracts. These contracts behave like bonds where users can set an amount in the factory, deploy the bond and then others can subscribe to the bonds. An issue I am facing at the moment is transferring funds from the factory to a bond contract.

This is the code (I've edited out the less relevant parts):

```
mapping (uint => Bond) private bonds;

function subscribeToBond(uint _bondId, uint _subscriptionAmount) public payable {
        Bond selectedBond = bonds[_bondId];
        //Checks
        payable(address(selectedBond)).transfer(_subscriptionAmount);
        subscriptionValue = _subscriptionAmount * selectedBond.rate();
        emit SubscribedToBond(_bondId, msg.sender, subscriptionValue);
```

The code fails at the .transfer(), with the error message saying:

```
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

My suspicion is that it's that the issue is to do with the factory contract's balance. The fact it doesn't have a balance. But if that is the issue, I'm unsure of how to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right regarding lack of balance. So, one way is to send ether when deploying the factory contract (it can be done easily in Remix). In this case, you should also define a **payable constructor**.

```
contract Factory{
   constructor() payable {
}}
```

Moreover, I am not sure what the type of Bond is. As you know, **explicit** conversions to and from **address** are allowed for uint160, integer literals, bytes20 and contract types.